# Difference between modify and patch installation sequence

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installshield, msi-patch

I need to repair the installation(.msi) as some files are removed. However, repair option is disabled by using following condition in LaunchCondition table.

> **PATCH OR NOT REINSTALL**

How should I restore missing files? We tried to use dummy patch(.msp) just in case if patch sequence repairs but no success. Also, these missing files can't be delivered in patch as these files were added in fresh installation using transform. For generating patch, InstallShield QuickPatch project is used which doesn't have capability to add new file unlike standard msi patch.

Although, we had tried the msi modify option without making any changes in feature selection and it seems to be working and restored missing files.So, I just want to understand how modify and patch sequences working. Why patch didn't restore the files but the modify option. Is it something related to **REINSTALLMODE, REINSTALL, ADDLOCAL** properties?

Comment: What is your version, edition of InstallShield?

Comment: 2020, Premier. But my question is specific to MSI technology.